# VS2012 Project+openssl (LNK2001)

Tags: c, windows, winapi, linker, openssl

Sorry for bad english, use Google.translate 
trying to include OpenSSL to project (DLL) for VS2012. 
 1. downloaded the [installer](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)(Win32 OpenSSL v1.0.1g, 16mb) and installed.
 2. build project
 3. and get an error

```
1>libeay32MDd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__GetUserObjectInformationW@20"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__GetProcessWindowStation@0"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__GetDesktopWindow@0"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__MessageBoxA@16"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__DeregisterEventSource@4"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(cryptlib.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__ReportEventA@36"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__DeleteDC@4"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__DeleteObject@4"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__GetBitmapBits@12"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__BitBlt@36"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__GetObjectA@12"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__SelectObject@8"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__CreateCompatibleBitmap@12"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__GetDeviceCaps@8"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__CreateCompatibleDC@4"
1>libeay32MDd.lib(rand_win.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp__CreateDCA@16"
```

Link Library

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ssleay32xx.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "libeay32xx.lib")
```

I tried different versions of libraries, just changed the /MT to /MD. 
Library is connected, as a function call

```
CMS_sign(&signcert,&pkey,&certs,&data,NULL);
```

does not lead to error. judging by the names of the functions are standard functions Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

resolve problem

```
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "GDI32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Advapi32.lib")
```

Comment: Solves the problem. Also note, that in VS this can also be solved by right-clicking project -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies. And add these libs there.